# Dividing variadic parameters in half

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I wrote a convenience function that gets some arguments and then sends them
to the right functions:

```
void combine(int a, int b, double one, double two) {
    funA(a,b);
    funB(one, two);
}
```

Now I want to do it again, but with variadic template parameters for both my `combine` function and the `funA`-`funB` pair:

```
//somewhere earlier in the code 
template<class U, class T> funA(U par1, T par2) {...}
template<class X, class Y> funB(X par1, Y par2) {...}

template<class ...ParamA, class ...ParamB>
void combine(ParamA...packA, ParamB...packB) {
     funA(packA...);
     funB(packB...);
}
```

This of course can't work because I need some way to divide the parameters list in half.
But what is more interesting is when I try to compile the above code with a call like
`combine(10, 'a', 12.0, true)` I get this error:

```
In instantiation of ‘void combine(ParamA ..., ParamB ...) [with ParamA = {}; ParamB = {int, char, double, bool}]’:
...
error: no matching function for call to ‘funA()’
....
error: no matching function for call to ‘funB(int&, char&, double&, bool&)’
```

which shows that `ParamB` "ate" all of the parameter list.

So, my question is: **is there a way to divide the parameter list of a function with variable template list in half?**. If not, **how else may I write my `combine` function?**

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

//somewhere earlier in the code 
template<class U, class T> void funA(U par1, T par2) {
    std::cout<<par1 <<' '<< par2 <<'\n';
}
// Use move-only type to check forwarding
template<class X> void funB(X par1, std::unique_ptr<int> par2) {
    std::cout<<par1 <<' '<< *par2 <<'\n';
}

// Call fnc with a subset of arguments, more general than we need for the partitioning.
template<typename Fnc,std::size_t...Is, typename...Args>
auto call_sub(Fnc fnc, std::index_sequence<Is...>, Args&&...args){
   
    auto tup = std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    // Extract relevant indices.
    return fnc(std::get<Is>(std::move(tup))...);
}

// Shift index sequences
template< std::size_t shift_amount,std::size_t...Is>
constexpr auto shift_sequence( std::index_sequence<Is...>){
    return  std::index_sequence<shift_amount +Is...>{};
}

template<class ...Params>
void combine(Params&&...pack) {
    static_assert(sizeof...(pack) % 2 == 0);
    constexpr std::size_t half = sizeof...(pack) /2;

    constexpr std::make_index_sequence<half> first_half;
    constexpr auto second_half = shift_sequence<half>(first_half);
    // Lambda must be used because funA nor funB are not functions, they are templates which cannot be passed around.
    call_sub([](auto&&...args){return funA(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);},
              first_half, std::forward<Params>(pack)...);
    call_sub([](auto&&...args){return funB(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);},
              second_half, std::forward<Params>(pack)...);


}
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    combine(1,2,3,std::make_unique<int>(10));
}
```

Output:

```
1 2
3 10
```

[Live Godbolt demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:49,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:49,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Ctuple%3E%0A%23include+%3Cutility%3E%0A%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cmemory%3E%0A%0A//somewhere+earlier+in+the+code+%0Atemplate%3Cclass+U,+class+T%3E+void+funA(U+par1,+T+par2)+%7B%0A++++std::cout%3C%3Cpar1+%3C%3C!%27+!%27%3C%3C+par2+%3C%3C!%27%5Cn!%27%3B%0A%7D%0A//+Use+move-only+type+to+check+forwarding%0Atemplate%3Cclass+X%3E+void+funB(X+par1,+std::unique_ptr%3Cint%3E+par2)+%7B%0A++++std::cout%3C%3Cpar1+%3C%3C!%27+!%27%3C%3C+*par2+%3C%3C!%27%5Cn!%27%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A//+Call+fnc+with+a+subset+of+arguments,+more+general+than+we+need+for+the+partitioning.%0Atemplate%3Ctypename+Fnc,std::size_t...Is,+typename...Args%3E%0Aauto+call_sub(Fnc+fnc,+std::index_sequence%3CIs...%3E,+Args%26%26...args)%7B%0A+++%0A++++auto+tup+%3D+std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward%3CArgs%3E(args)...)%3B%0A++++//+Extract+relevant+indices.%0A++++return+fnc(std::get%3CIs%3E(std::move(tup))...)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A//+Shift+index+sequences%0Atemplate%3C+std::size_t+shift_amount,std::size_t...Is%3E%0Aconstexpr+auto+shift_sequence(+std::index_sequence%3CIs...%3E)%7B%0A++++return++std::index_sequence%3Cshift_amount+%2BIs...%3E%7B%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atemplate%3Cclass+...Params%3E%0Avoid+combine(Params%26%26...pack)+%7B%0A++++static_assert(sizeof...(pack)+%25+2+%3D%3D+0)%3B%0A++++constexpr+std::size_t+half+%3D+sizeof...(pack)+/2%3B%0A%0A++++constexpr+std::make_index_sequence%3Chalf%3E+first_half%3B%0A++++constexpr+auto+second_half+%3D+shift_sequence%3Chalf%3E(first_half)%3B%0A++++//+Lambda+must+be+used+because+funA+nor+funB+are+not+functions,+they+are+templates+which+cannot+be+passed+around.%0A++++call_sub(%5B%5D(auto%26%26...args)%7Breturn+funA(std::forward%3Cdecltype(args)%3E(args)...)%3B%7D,%0A++++++++++++++first_half,+std::forward%3CParams%3E(pack)...)%3B%0A++++call_sub(%5B%5D(auto%26%26...args)%7Breturn+funB(std::forward%3Cdecltype(args)%3E(args)...)%3B%7D,%0A++++++++++++++second_half,+std::forward%3CParams%3E(pack)...)%3B%0A%0A%0A%7D%0Aint+main+(int+argc,+char+*argv%5B%5D)%0A%7B%0A++++combine(1,2,3,std::make_unique%3Cint%3E(10))%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:57.639987549568154,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:42.36001245043185,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%231+with+x86-64+clang+(trunk)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:42.36001245043185,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)